# Creating a second menu on Twenty Eleven aligned right from the first

Tags: css, menus, theme-twenty-eleven

I'm a bit new here.  But I did attempt to Google this (etc.), without much luck.  Basically, I'm trying to set up a second menu on Twenty Eleven that will line up to the right of the normal one (while keeping the normal one).

In other words, something like this:

|Home | First_Page | Second_Page | . . . (empty space) . . . | 2nd-to-last-page | Last page

Is there a relatively simple way to do that?  I've gotten more used to CSS lately (working with Wordpress), so I can handle basic-to-moderate techniques there (and I've been doing PHP for years now, so not too many issues there).  I'm just not sure where to begin :).

Thanks!
- Alex

Answer (score 1):

- Register a second sidebar.
- Call it in your child theme where TwentyEleven calls the first one.
- Let it float and adjust the CSS for the first menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add more options to the right of the existing menu wouldn't it be easy to just include the additional menu items you want in the default menu that is displayed and then position them to the right of the existing menu items.

You could do this using custom menus - [here](http://templatic.com/news/wordpress-3-0-menu-management/) is a good post on how to set them up.